# How to read CSV with column with more than one element in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have the following CSV file:

```
id;name;duration;predecessors;
10;A;7;;
20;B;10;10;
25;B2;3;10;
30;C;5;10;
40;D;5;20,30, 25;
```

That is, the last row, in the fourth column I have three elements (20,30,25) separated by comma.

I have the following code:

```
csv_file = open(path_to_csv, 'r')
csv_file_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

first_row = True
for row in csv_file_reader :

    if not first_row:
        print(row)

    else :
        first_row = False
```

but I get a weird output:

```
['10;A;7;;']
['20;B;10;10;']
['25;B2;3;10;']
['30;C;5;10;']
['40;D;5;20', '30', ' 25;']
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your files uses `;` as the delimiter, not `,`

Comment: BTW, you don't need that `if` test inside the loop. Instead, put this before the loop to skip the 1st line: `next(csv_file_reader)`

Answer (score 2):

You have specified CSV in your description, which stands for **C**omma **S**eparated **V**alues.  However, your data uses semicolons.

Consider specifying the delimiter as `;` for the CSV library:

```
with open(path_to_csv, 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_file_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')

    ...
```

And while we're here, note the change to using the `with` statement to open the file.  The `with` statement allows you to open the file in a language-robust manner.  No matter *what* happens (exception, quit, etc.), Python guarantees that the file will be closed and all resources accounted for.  You don't need to close the file, just exit the block (unindent).  It's "Pythonic" and a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

✓ **@Antonio**, I appreciate the above answer. As we know CSV is a file with comma separated values and Python's **csv** module works based on this, by default.

✓ No problem, you can still read from it without using **csv** module.

✓ Based on your provided input in problem I have written another simple solution without using any Python module to read CSVs (it's ok for simple tasks).

> Please **read, try** and **comment** if you are not satisfied with the code or if it fails for some of your test cases.I will modify and make it workable.

#### » Data.csv

```
id;name;duration;predecessors;
10;A;7;;
20;B;10;10;
25;B2;3;10;
30;C;5;10;
40;D;5;20,30, 25;
```

Now, have a look at the below code (that finds and prints all the lines with 4th column having more than one elements):

```
with open ("Data.csv") as csv_file:
    for line in csv_file.readlines()[1:]:
        arr = line.strip().split(";")
        if len(arr[3].split(",") )> 1:
            print(line) # 40;D;5;20,30, 25;
```